# How to reduce an xarray dataset by selecting dimensions inside boundaries?

Tags: python, coordinates, dask, python-xarray, clip

I have a large dataset that I would like to clip. But the file is way too large.

[image]

I want to divide the big task into smaller ones (I tried to make it work with chunks but no results were found). 
I created a coordinate box `(xmax, xmin, ymax, ymin)` and I want to select from my dataset data that is inside this box. 
I tried the `xr.sel()` method, but it doesn't seem to work with boundaries.

Is there a way to do so? 
Or is there a way to use the `rio.clip` method chunk by chunk?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried to make it work with chunks but no results found" ?
Could you share the code you tried to execute and the error/result you get ?

Comment: ^ same for "I tried the xr.sel() method". What did you try and how did it fail? `sel()` should support slicing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.